# Can a self-executing anonymous function conflict with or flummox MOD_REWRITE?

Tags: jquery, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I have a RewriteRule for a static URL that correctly translates to a dynamic URL. However the source code is only processed if I append an R flag to the RewriteRule; without an R flag, the source code is delivered to the browser, but it is not rendered, i.e. all I get is a white screen, but "view source" reveals that the correct code was in fact delivered to the browser.

HOWEVER: The displaying of the page within the code is accomplished in a self-executing anonymous JQUERY function. It appears that although the RewriteRule allows the code to be sent to the browser, the self-executing JQUERY function simply doesn't execute.

For MOD_REWRITE, should code that relies on routines like this be called with specific RewriteRule flags that aren't immediately obvious?  The code can be viewed here:

https://home.comcast.net/~tom.brodhead/problem.txt

The self-calling anonymous function begins at line 84.

Many thanks for any suggestions,
Tom

Here's a rewrite rule:

```
^g([0-9-]+)/w([0-9-]+)/?$ /gallery.php?gallery_id=$1#artwork.php?artwork_id=$2 [NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you show the exact rewriterule that works and the one that doesn't work?

Comment: This may help explain: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1017.htm

Comment: If I put that code in X.HTM and go to it directly, like this: mysite/x.htm then it executes. However, it my rewrite rule is even this: RewriteRule ^g$ /x.htm [NC,L] and I execute it this way: mysite/g then the code is served to the browser but it doesn't execute. If, however I add an R flag to the rewrite rule, like this: ^g$ /x.htm [NC,L,R] then the code is served to the browser and the page is rasterized, however with X.HTM showing in the URL bar. I'm convinced it has to do with the self-calling anonymous function. Any thoughts?

Comment: At this point, I'd say you need to diagnose exactly what is different in what the browser sees between the two cases.  Do a view/source in the browser in each case and save those to local files and then compare.  There's nothing magic about the self calling anonymous function.  If it's not working, it's probably because there's a script error somewhere that causes script execution to abort.

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to match with `^g$` as the pattern?  My guess is that you are using relative paths for loading other scripts so those relative paths will only work from certain base URLs.  One difference between using the `[R]` flag and not using it is what the base URL shows in the browser which can affect other relative URLs in the document.  When you use the `[R]` flag it literally tells the browser to go load a different URL and that becomes the actual URL.  When you don't have the `[R]` flag, the contents of the file are replaced, but the URL does not change.

Answer (score 0):

With the `[R]` flag the browser is physically redirected to a different URL and the browser then goes and fetches the content from that new URL.  That second URL becomes the URL that shows in the browser and is the base URL for that page that all relative URLs are evaluated against.

Without the `[R]` flag, the content of the original URL is just rewritten to have different content and the URL in the browser stays what was originally requested (the browser is unaware of the rewrite in this case).  All relative URLs in the browser are evaluated relative to that original URL.

You haven't shared what the original URL is that this RewriteRule is catching, but if it's at a different path than `/x.htm`, then this will make a huge difference.

And, you are loading scripts using relative paths here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
```

So, if you change the location of the base URL, these scripts could easily start or stop loading properly.

Since you've disclosed so little detail about the actual URLs being used here, the actual errors shown in the browser, etc... this is just a theory at this point.  But, if this theory is correct, then you can fix the issue several different ways.  The easiest is to just stop using relative paths that will work or not depending upon the location of the base URL.  You don't need to put the domain in the paths, but you can start them at the root `/path/myscript.js` so they become independent of the base URL path.

Other solutions could involve setting a base href in the HTML file to control what relative URLs are evaluated against independent of the page URL.

Or you could set up rewrite URLs for the missing script files at the path they are being requested on.

If this is happening, you should also be able to see script loading errors in the browser's error console when the page isn't working properly.

And, the network tab in the Chrome debugger should show exactly which URL requests are not loading properly and exactly what URL was being requested.

---

FYI, you probably don't want to use the `[R]` flag for a regular production page URL because it's an extra roundtrip between client and server which adds an inefficiency.

---

I'm also a little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish with a rewrite rule targeted at `^g$`.  If you could explain that also, there may be other solutions in changing the rewrite rule.

Comment: 1) This is code written by someone else that I'm amending.
2) The $g^ is just an example of the simplest kind of rewrite...my point being that even a rewrite of a single letter doesn't work, i.e. it has nothing to do with parameters not being passed to the rewrite.
3) I have compare the code served to the browser when I go directly to the page in question with the code served by rewriting using the [R] flag and with code served by rewriting *without* the [R] flag AND IT IS EXACTLY THE SAME EACH TIME.
4) When I load this code from a dedicated, generic file (X.HTML) it executes just fine.

Comment: 5) There is page is set in its header to be invisible until it is processed by the self-executing Jquery function.
6) When the header instruction to make the contents invisible is REMmed out, the page *displays* except for the styling information and other things in the Query self-executing function.

Comment: 7) Ergo, the self-executing Query function is NOT executing when the page is being served internally.

Comment: @Tom - It sure sounds like this is an issue with relative paths that causes the scripts before the self executing function to not load which makes the first function that tries to use them (your self executing function) fail.  Have you looked in the debug console to see what page resources are not loading properly?  I could probably solve this in minutes if I could see a live version of the non-working page because there are clearly resource loading errors to be seen.  I've asked you multiple times to show me the actual two versions of THE rule for this particular page, but you refuse.  Why?

Comment: 8) The relative paths of the Javascript locations are not a problem...everything is in the right location.
9) "the original URL is that this RewriteRule is catching, but if it's at a different path than /x.htm"...the original URL is *not* at a different path. I've provided the most generic distillation of the files, locations, etc. for ease in decoding the problem.

Comment: @Tom - I've also asked you to look in the debug console to see what loading errors there are and to look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger to see what resources are not loading.  Is there a reason you are ignoring these pieces of advice?

Comment: @Tom - ease of decoding the problem does not contain enough information to see or understand the problem.  You're at 17 hours with no answer.  Why not provide more information when requested?  Clearly something in the unworking page is not loading properly.  The goal here is to figure out what.

Comment: RewriteRule ^g([0-9-]+)/w([0-9-]+)/?$ /gallery.php?gallery_id=$1#artwork.php?artwork_id=$2 [NE,NC,L]

Comment: @Tom - If you can let me see a link to the non-working page, I'll look at what isn't loading properly.

Comment: Remember: When I save the served code (which is *exactly* the same whether I use the dynamic URL or the static URL interpreted by the MOD_REWRITE) to X.HTML and load it, the page loads correctly. Ergo, there's *NO* problem with the Javascript routines loading...they do in fact load in this scenario, and are accessible.

Comment: @Tom - yeah, but something is different in the situation where it doesn't work.  That's what we're trying to figure out.  So, it's a bit frustrating to me when you insist nothing is different - that simply can't be true.  And, when the same script that doesn't work, that means something that script depends on is different.  I probably need to see the actual non-working live page to go further.  This remote control debugging is not very efficient on this problem.

Comment: I don't have a high enough "reputation" on this site to move this to a chat; the code on the live site works just fine, as it does on my local server. I'm trying to develop the rewrite rule on my local server before uploading the modified .htaccess file to the live server. We'd have to do Skype or some form of screen sharing in order to go further, and I don't know how to do that here without exposing my email, etc.

Comment: @Tom - Can you make a separate rewrite rule on the production site that isn't used by normal traffic that exhibits the problem so I can take a look.  I'm headed out shortly so can't work on this more right now.